# Que desde el catch lance un mensaje usando throw

Tags: c++, excepciones

Estoy estudiando sobre las excepciones y los pdf que tengo hablan muy poco sobre las especificación de excepciones de la forma *throw (lista de excepciones)* 
Encontré este código en un archivo cpp y lo he tratado de entender pero me rompo la cabeza como es que un `throw` puede lanzar un comentario después de encontrar un error `bad_alloc` si está dentro del `catch` aquí les dejo el código para que me digan como ocurriría la excepción.

```
void errorBadAlloc(int *t) throw (const char *)
{
   try
   {
      int *t;
      t = new int[99999999999999999];
   }
   catch(std::bad_alloc)
   {
      throw "ERROR: unable to allocate new buffer for Vector\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Cuando se piden libros o enlaces, se está buscando respuestas basadas en opiniones, algo que haría que tu pregunta sea cerrada... En cambio, te recomiendo realizar la pregunta enfocada puntualmente al problema que estás teniendo, o al concepto que no estás entendiendo, de modo que tenga una única respuesta correcta.

Comment: tienes razón. La pregunta seria ¿Como hago para que desde el catch lance el mensaje "ERROR: unable to allocate new buffer for Vector\n" usando el throw.? o es q no se puede y ese ejemplo esta mal hecho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> los pdf que tengo hablan muy poco sobre las especificación de excepciones de la forma throw

`throw` es la forma que tiene c++ de lanzar excepciones.

Cuando se lanza una excepción el ciclo de ejecución habitual se rompe y se empieza a retroceder en la pila de llamadas hasta que se captura la excepción o se finaliza el programa.

> o he tratado de entender pero me rompo la cabeza como es que un `throw` puede lanzar un comentario después de encontrar un error `bad_alloc` si está dentro del `catch`

`catch` es el mecanismo empleado para capturar las excepciones. Puedes entender `catch` como una especie de función que espera recibir una excepción de un tipo determinado (o de alguna de sus hijas vía herencia). Puedes colocar tantos `catch` como sean necesarios justo después de un `try`:

```
int main()
{
  try
  {
    throw 5;
  }

  catch( const std::bad_alloc&)
  {
    // Aqui se capturaría bad_alloc o derivadas
  }

  catch( const std::exception& )
  {
    // Aqui se capturarian todas las excepciones que hereden de std::exception
    // excepto bad_alloc, que se capturaria en el catch anterior
  }

  catch( int valor )
  {
    // Aqui se capturarian las excepciones de tipo int
    // Con el throw del ejemplo el código acabaría aquí
  }

  catch( ... )
  {
    // Aqui se capturan el resto de excepciones
    // Lo malo de esta captura es que no puedes saber qué ha pasado
  }
}
```

Ahora bien, ¿Cómo funciona eso de lanzar excepciones dentro de un `catch`.

La filosofía de las excepciones es lanzarlas cuando se produce un error que no puedes gestionar en la capa de código donde te encuentras actualmente y necesitas que una capa superior gestione el error. La capa que capture el error debe ser aquella capaz de ofrecer una solución al problema.

Cuando una excepción es capturada dentro de un `catch`, la excepción pasa a estar descartada ya que se entiende que si capturas una excepción en un punto es porque vas a tomar cartas en el asunto en dicho punto.

Entonces, en el momento de capturar una excepción pueden suceder cuatro cosas:

1. Consigues que el programa se recupere y el programa puede seguir funcionando.
2. El error producido es crítico y debes cerrar el programa
3. Las acciones que intentan recuperarse del error provocan un nuevo error.
4. La capa que captura la excepción únicamente puede recuperarse de parte del problema y debe lanzar de nuevo la excepción.

Tu estás preguntando concretamente por el caso 3. Esto es algo perfectamente legal y tiene su utilidad. Piensa por ejemplo que para recuperarte del error tienes que abrir un fichero para guardar un log... y resulta que el sistema no te deja abrir el fichero ¿qué haces? Una posible solución puede ser lanzar una excepción indicando el problema a ver si se puede encontrar una solución en una capa superior de código.

Lo que sucede cuando escribes `throw [excepcion];` dentro de un `catch` es que la excepción que has capturado se descarta y es sustituida por la nueva excepción. En la pila de las excepciones únicamente hay sitio para un elemento, por lo que si intentas introducir un elemento el existente debe ser descartado.

Lanzar una excepción dentro de un `catch` tiene los mismos efectos que lanzar la excepción desde cualquier otra parte del código... el código subirá funciones en la pila hasta encontrarse con un bloque `try`.

El caso 4 es una variación del caso 3 y se consigue poniendo simplemente `throw`:

```
catch( const std::exception& exc)
{
  // ...
  throw; // Se vuelve a lanzar la excepción
}
```

Lo que se consigue entonces es que la excepción que has capturado en el `catch` vuelve a ser lanzada, lo que permite que una capa superior de tu aplicación la capture para seguir realizando operaciones de mantenimiento.

¿Y qué diferencia hay entre ese ejemplo y el siguiente?

```
catch( const std::exception& exc)
{
  // ...
  throw exc;
}
```

La diferencia es que en este segundo ejemplo se está lanzando una copia de la excepción y esto puede ser problemático:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

void func1()
{
  throw std::out_of_range("");
}

void func2()
{
  try
  {
    func1();
  }

  catch( const std::exception& exc )
  {
    throw exc;
  }
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    func2();
  }

  catch( const std::bad_alloc& exc )
  {
    std::cout << "bad_alloc\n ;
  }

  catch( const std::exception& exc )
  {
    std::cout << "exception\n ;
  }
}
```

Si ejecutas este ejemplo el programa imprimirá `exception` en vez de `bad_alloc`. ¿Por qué? El motivo es que `func2()` ha capturado la excepción como si fuese de tipo `std::exception` (está empleando polimorfismo) y al hacer `throw exc` está haciendo una copia de `std::exception` èn vez de hacer una copia de `std::bad_alloc`.

El error se soluciona dejando `throw` a secas:

```
void func2()
{
  try
  {
    func1();
  }

  catch( const std::exception& exc )
  {
    throw;
  }
}
```

Ahora el programa imprimirá `bad_alloc`.

Y ahora, hablando de tu ejemplo:

```
void errorBadAlloc(int *t) throw (const char *)
{
   try
   {
      int *t;
      t = new int[99999999999999999];
   }
   catch(std::bad_alloc)
   {
      throw "ERROR: unable to allocate new buffer for Vector\n";
   }
}
```

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente:

- Si el programa es incapaz de realizar la memoria pedida, la instrucción `new` lanzará una excepción de tipo `bad_alloc`.
- La excepción será capturada por el `try` y se llamará a la captura realizada por el único `catch` que hay, ya que el mismo es compatible con las excepciones de tipo `bad_alloc`.
- Durante la captura se lanza una nueva excepción, esta vez es de tipo `const char*`. La excepción de tipo `bad_alloc` es decartada y sustituida por la nueva excepción.
- La ejecución del programa abandona el ejemplo de tu código en busca de una nueva captura realizada con `try`.

Como nota final piensa que es una buena práctica disponer de una jerarquía de excepciones y a ser posible intenta que dicha jerarquía herede de `std::exception`. El motivo es que este sistema facilita la captura de excepciones, como has podido ver durante la lectura de esta respuesta. Efectivamente es totalmente legal lanzar una excepción de tipo `const char*`, pero capturar este tipo de excepciones no es habitual y una excepción no controlada provoca el cierre de la aplicación... así que ya sabes.

Comment: pero me sale este error por pantalla :
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

y nunca se imprime "ERROR: unable to allocate new buffer for Vector\n "
¿Porque pasa esto?

Comment: @Mucacran Porque no has capturado esa excepción. Prueba esto en el main: `try{ int* t; errorBadAlloc(t); } catch( const char* exc ) { std::cout << "CAPTURADA: " << exc; }`

Comment: el 'char const*' como he leído en la instrucción queme compartio debe ayudar a imprimir ese cadena de palabras, porque captura la excepcion bad_alloc y con el throw debe lanzarlo por pantalla el texto. Si me equivoco corrigame no mas. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: @Mucacran `throw` lanza una nueva excepción... no interactua para nada con la consola. Para escribir en la consola debes usar `cout`

Comment: Muchas gracias, en su comentario respondió mi pregunta muchas gracias le quedo agradecido mucho (en donde desde el main llamo al try que esta en la función, hay si imprime).
gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui te dejo un par de link donde hay ejemplos y estructuras.

http://c.conclase.net/curso/?cap=043c

http://elvex.ugr.es/decsai/builder/intro/6.html